# How to make Arc Progress Bar in Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I want to create an arc progress bar as an audio player but I am not achieving the exact View.

I have also tried some third party libraries, but the progress bar is not the same as I want.

This is what I want
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OIrRCgqJHxUzQCAZn3t23dDwjqdvIvkp/view?usp=sharing

but this is what I am getting
https://drive.google.com/file/d/14Lh367bWR1nA7_XIXepZudpnb5hsdOkY/view?usp=sharing

Comment: show us what have you tried.

Comment: @RatulSharker I am using this library 
https://github.com/EranBoudjnah/MTCircularSlider
and in my code i am doing this,

        progressSlider.applyAttributes([
            Attributes.minTrackTint(.lightGray),
            Attributes.maxTrackTint(.darkGray),
            Attributes.trackWidth(8),
            Attributes.trackShadowRadius(0),
            Attributes.trackShadowDepth(0),
            Attributes.trackMinAngle(0),
            Attributes.trackMaxAngle(180),
            Attributes.hasThumb(true)
            ])

Comment: if the 3rd party does not fit you requirement, you have to write your own control. Did you tried that ?

Comment: @RatulSharker , I don't know how to customize its shape as arc view. If you have any link or sample code then please provide me with it.

Comment: check here https://www.raywenderlich.com/411-core-graphics-tutorial-part-1-getting-started

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with the help of `Autolayout` and some radius modification with the below library.

Library : https://github.com/EranBoudjnah/MTCircularSlider

**Autolayout setup for Circular Slider:**

1. Align Center X to Superview.

[image]

2. Proportional Width to superview (Multiplier - 1.2).

[image]

3. Proportional Height to superview (Multiplier - 0.7).

[image]

4. Bottom 0 to superview.

[image]

By this, you can achieve your layout.

Now 2nd step to limit your slider you need to set a radius of your slider as per your requirements of the design.

As per the above layout radius should be like below value.

```
Track Min Angle: 27

Track Max Angle: 153
```

By setting the above angle you will achieve your slider the same as ref image.

Ref Output :

[image]

Hope this will helps to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0):

First of all its not 180 degrees what you want as seen on the picture. So first of all you may want to try give it bigger radius and move it slightly down and set up min/max angles accordingly. However I would recommend implementing your own control as you won't rely on any library and it's not even hard. You can try this tutorial for example on [raywenderlich.com](https://www.raywenderlich.com/5294-how-to-make-a-custom-control-tutorial-a-reusable-knob).